# Spring boot ressource server with azure ad

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, azure-active-directory

I am running into an issue and asking for any help.
I got a react app running and there I log in with the oidc azure ad. I am getting all information I wanted as well as a jwt.

Now I want my frontend to call routes on my spring boot backend. That's why I decided that my backend is a resource server. And here I want to validate the provided JWT.
As soon as I do a request I got the following error:

> Failed to lazily resolve the supplied JwtDecoder instance

> Unable to resolve the Configuration with the provided Issuer of
> "https://login.microsoftonline.com/3d1f9219-b455-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/wsfed"

I think that my issuer-uri is wrong. But I cannot find a solution for this.
Here is my filterChain method:

```
@Bean
open fun filterChain(http: HttpSecurity) : SecurityFilterChain{
    http
        .authorizeHttpRequests{
            authorize -> authorize.antMatchers("/**").hasAnyAuthority("SCOPE_user.read")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        }
        .oauth2ResourceServer{
            oauth2 -> oauth2.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults())
        }
    return http.build()
}
```

and thats my application.yml

```
spring:
    security:
        oauth2:
          resourceserver:
            jwt:
              issuer-uri: https://login.microsoftonline.com/3d1f9219-b455-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/wsfed
```

I've already tried other issuer-uris like
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/keys
[https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/discovery/keys?appid={client_id}](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant_id%7D/discovery/keys?appid=%7Bclient_id%7D)

but without success.

I know this is kotlin but I am fine with java too.

EDIT:

I've changed the issuer-uri to:
[https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/v2.0](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant-id%7D/v2.0)

But now I am facing 401 Unauthorized http error

Comment: I followed this guide from microsoft (protect a resource server/api)[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/spring-boot-starter-for-azure-active-directory-developer-guide#protect-a-resource-serverapi].  Remember to provide a valid jwt, using the client as audience.

Comment: @meridsa thanks, i have create a fresh spring boot project. with just a Controller returning "Hello" and the application.yml as shown in the docs you have postet. But iI am getting 401 error

Comment: Have you gotten any help with this, I am also getting 401 error, with log message Failed to authenticate since the JWT was invalid. I can confirm that the token is still valid